# use riot dll in C#

Tags: c#, dll

how to use RIOT dll in C# application? is there a way that i can use it in my program.

Comment: what did you do? show us that you did some work and research into this...? how did you do it? how far have you got? these are the vitals that is needed for posting a decent question instead of getting lazy and asking us to fill in the blanks for you with no emphasis on effort on your part....

Comment: i am not lazy i have searched on riot's site that it is possible to use with any programming language. But i'm not sure how can i do that i tried to add reference to the dll and do it but its not working that for me.

Comment: Help us help you.  Provide us some code to look at, an exception, or something that shows what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

It's called p/Invoke. This article tells you (almost) everything you need to know about the subject. It is specific to the Win32 API, but your RIOT API will work exactly the same way.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your help article which u provided is really helpful to me and I got to learn some thing new from you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to RIOT's [developer reference guide](http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/dll-version/), "Riot.dll can be used with any programming language capable of using dynamic link libraries. This includes C/C++, Visual Basic, C#, Object Pascal/Delphi, Perl."

So I would say, yes, you can use it in your C# application.

Comment: I think he/she means how not if

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a [DLLImport("RIOT.dll")] tag over your methods using the header files, as I have done with the [Bass](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html) project. It isn't that hard, you can probably find examples on the internet.